# How to make Watson Discovery return query result on Node-RED with Telegram app?

Tags: ibm-watson, node-red, watson-discovery

[Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEC2o.png)

Above I have a Node-RED flow. I have a chatbot on telegram and I wish for the chatbot to undergo the flow. The idea of the flow is that an end user will send their input (such as "/search country") then the discovery node will go through my person Watson Discovery data collection which contains documents. Then the chatbot should return back with the query results of the Watson Discovery.

Currently I have tried the approach and done something similar to this url: https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/how-to-create-a-watson-chatbot-on-nodered/ However this link does not contain anything about Watson Discovery.

When I try to do a query, it tells me that my "Prepare for Telegram" node is getting an error [Node Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOsWv.png).

Attached here is the code I have for "Prepare for Telegram" [Prepare for Telegram code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jI5S9.png)

Then here are the parameters that I put for the Discovery node [Discovery Node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1HQ1.png)

So I believe the error is from the code of the "Prepare for Telegram" as when I try a query it highlights that node. I request that someone please help me with this node.

Comment: Step 1. Would be to make the Discovery Node work standalone. - https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-red-labs/tree/master/basic_examples/discovery

Comment: @chughts I have already used this but I need it to integrate with Telegram

Comment: Step 2. Use what you learnt from step 1 to configure the discovery node in your telegram flow.